# DataStax Stargate Document API

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, datastax, stargate-oss

What does the `a JSON blob with search filters, allowed operators: $eq, $ne, $in, $nin, $gt, $lt, $gte, $lte, $exists` in the Swagger documentation that is shown in the DataStax Document API Swagger UI, it's not that documented so I want to ask if the query string is based on MongoDB?

Comment: I mean these exact same operators are in MongoDB's query language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Document API exposed on top of Cassandra is provided by the open source project [**Stargate**](https://stargate.io/), indeed developed by Datastax and embedded in their Saas solution [Astra](https://astra.datastax.com).

The JSON query String than you created is parsed and converted in a proper CQL query under the hood.

Source code doesn't lie you can find the full code [here](https://github.com/stargate/stargate/blob/9bda614cc6fc1885fb6484887d1dd5c705c8ab43/restapi/src/main/java/io/stargate/web/docsapi/resources/DocumentResourceV2.java#L613) and specially parsing of the where clause [here](https://github.com/stargate/stargate/blob/9bda614cc6fc1885fb6484887d1dd5c705c8ab43/restapi/src/main/java/io/stargate/web/docsapi/service/DocumentService.java#L535)

```
public List<FilterCondition> convertToFilterOps(
 List<PathSegment> prependedPath, 
 JsonNode filterJson) {
 
 List<FilterCondition> conditions = new ArrayList<>();

 if (!filterJson.isObject()) {
  throw new DocumentAPIRequestException("Search was expecting a JSON object as input.");
 }

 ObjectNode input = (ObjectNode) filterJson;
 Iterator<String> fields = input.fieldNames();
 while (fields.hasNext()) {
  String fieldName = fields.next();
  if (fieldName.isEmpty()) {
    throw new DocumentAPIRequestException(
        "The field(s) you are searching for can't be the empty string!");
  }
 ...
```

Answer (score 5):

The query string is pretty similar in spirit to what you'd find with Mongo.

Here are some sample where clauses to give an idea:

`{"name": {"$eq": "Eric"}}` - simple enough, matches documents that have a field `name` with value `Eric`

`{"a.age": {"$gt": 0}}` - You can also reference nested fields in a document

`{"friends.[0].name": {"$in": ["Cassandra"]}}` - Array elements are referenced using `[]`, this would match if the document's first friend is named Cassandra.

`{"friends.*.age": {"$gte": 24}}` - Wildcard `*` can be used to match any element in an array, or any field at a particular level of nesting. This matches any friend whose age is >= 24.